# Geometry Node - Texture disapear at "Join Geometry"

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry-nodes

I have a little problem over here. :-)

it seems that "join geometry" at the geometry node breaks my texture or maybe the uv map.

Thats the uv map:

[image: uv]

That is the material:

[image: material]

after apply a geometry node, the texture disapear:

[image]

When i "remove" the "join geometry" node - then the texture work again:

[image]

The material are the right material. When i remove the image and put only a color at the material - then this is the right one. Maybe broke the uv map at "join geometry"? How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://developer.blender.org/T85962). To solve this, use attribute node (put the name of UV map in the name field) instead UV map in shader editor:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! :-D This solved the problem! Please note: you must use the same name at the attribute node as the uv map.